# Declaring DataRow within a foreach or for Loop

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, datarow

The situation is this. I've got a select query that gets and array of DataRows that I want to insert into a new DataTable.

But when trying to add the Row I get the following error:

*"Row already belongs to another Table".*

So I tried creating and initializing a new DataRow within the loop(for and foreach loop) then throw an error when initializing the DataRow:

*"Inaccessible due to its protection level"*

Any Ideas? Feels like I'm missing something silly.

My Code for the first Error:

```
var DRCurrentAuspragung = _DTAuspragung.Select(@"MerkmalID = "+Convert.ToString(MerkmalID));

        _DTCurrentAuspragung = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < DRCurrentAuspragung.Length;i++ )
        {
            DataRow RowAdd = DRCurrentAuspragung[i];
            _DTCurrentAuspragung.Rows.Add(RowAdd);
        }
```

And for the second error:

```
var DRCurrentAuspragung = _DTAuspragung.Select(@"MerkmalID = "+Convert.ToString(MerkmalID));

        _DTCurrentAuspragung = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataRow dr in DRCurrentAuspragung)
        {
            DataRow RowAdd = new DataRow();
            RowAdd = dr;
            _DTCurrentAuspragung.Rows.Add(RowAdd);
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of this exception is one `DataRow` object cannot belong to more than one table. One solution, is to create a copy of this row with the help of the `ImportRow` method:

```
  _DTCurrentAuspragung.ImportRow(RowAdd);
```

And don't forget to use `Clone()` after selecting rows, beacause both of these tables must have the same structure:

```
DataTable _DTCurrentAuspragung = _DTAuspragung.Clone();
```

***So, the result is:***

```
 var DRCurrentAuspragung = _DTAuspragung.Select(@"MerkmalID = " + Convert.ToString(MerkmalID));

 _DTCurrentAuspragung = _DTAuspragung.Clone();
 for (int i = 0; i < DRCurrentAuspragung.Length; i++ )
 {
         DataRow RowAdd = DRCurrentAuspragung[i];
         _DTCurrentAuspragung.ImportRow(RowAdd);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the [ImportRow()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method. Remember that the table you're importing rows into has to have the same structure as the table the row you're importing belongs to (column names and types)